# SharePoint site creation is very slow in certain site collections

Tags: 2010, site-collection, site-template, performance, site-creation

SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

We have two site collections which are very slow when it comes to creating content like sites, lists, and libraries and accessing settings for existing objects. I would say creating a site takes about 3-5 minutes from the time you select a template. Sometimes, it can take as long as 10 minutes. If, on the other hand, I create a new site collection site creation is almost instant. Both these problem site collections have their own content database.

I looked at the databases. One is about 130GB and the other is 40GB. I know MS recommends databases be around the 100GB, but it also states they can be as large as 200GB. I copied the DBs to our dev server and used DBCC to check for index fragmentation and even reindexed the databases to rule out problems with the databases. Everything came back fine.

Here is our current config:

- 2 WFE's 12GB RAM, 4 core processors @ 2.6GHz, VM
- 1 App Server, 8GB
  RAM, 4 core processors @ 2.6GHz, VM
- 1 DB Server, SQL 2008, Physical
  server. Not sure of the specs but I am sure they pretty beefy

Just as an experiment, I tried creating sites with powershell. I noticed that when I create a site without specifying a template, it is created in seconds. Follwing that, when I access the site I have to select a template. The first time I selected the team template. As expected, it took forever. The second time I selected the blank site template, which took about 27 seconds to create the site.

I am at a loss as to why these to site collections are so slow. Could there be something wrong with our team site template? How do you troubleshoot that?

Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1/20/15: I am still not able to find the source of the slowness. I have run profiler and DBCC against the database, reindexed, etc but performance is still slow. May have to consult with our contractor...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely with SQL - which is the source of 95% of all SharePoint performance problems.

If you want to see what is actually happening, you can go medium level and run some PerfMon counters and it will tell you where the latency is.  If you want more detail you can run  SQL profiler which will tell you which operations are actually your bottle neck.

There are multiple points where things can get held up.  It may be that requests are being queued and so they can't move off the SharePoint server, or they are held at SQL.  It may be IOPS issue, it may be a TempDB issue (especially if it's a shared instance). One of the above methods should help you locate the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. I will look into the SQL server more using perfmon and profiler. Once I determine the root cause, I will post something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a Site with the OOB Team Template site to compare times and then I think you can pretty much point to your custom template as the issue.

Answer (score -1):

although database may be one of the problems, try reducing the **page-weight**, with the tags you would use. Also, I recommend using "DIV" tags verses html tables.  Also, Search your web browser on the internet for words like "Liquid Design". **"Div"** tags hold less page bloat than html tables being rendered in the web browser.

***For good liquid design techniques***

visit: http://www.csszengarden.com/